# I am entering date as "10/09/2019" in my ASP.NET MVC & Entity Framework project but in database it is saved as "1.1.0001 00:00:00"

Tags: angular, entity-framework

I am facing a problem with date when I input any date the debugger shows the "1.1.0001" date format and also in database it is saving as 1.1.0001. I have tried many solutions like decorating properties but none of these worked.

I'm facing this issue in updating and adding data. I am using AngularJs in my project.

Here is my code.. I want the same date to be entered in db as users input.

```js
//attribute properties//
public partial class expense
{
        public int expenseId { get; set; }
        public string expensetype { get; set; }
        public double amount { get; set; }
        public string detail { get; set; }
        public int RId { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MMMMM-dd}")]
        public System.DateTime date { get; set; }
    
        public virtual registration registration { get; set; }
}
    
// controller class
public JsonResult Addnewexpenses(expense expenses)
{
    string res = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        loginDB ldb = new loginDB();
        int id = ldb.getid(Session["Email"]);
        expenses.RId = id;

        ldb.Addnewexpenses(expenses);
        res = "Add";
    }
    catch
    {
        res = "failed";
    }

    return Json(res, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
        
// db class
public void Addnewexpenses(expense expenses)
{
    using (loginApplicationEntities db = new loginApplicationEntities())
    {
        db.expenses.Add(expenses);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<form name="addexpense">
            <div data-ng-init="loadrecord(@Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]))">
                <div class="input-group">
                    @*<input type="text" ng-model="expensesdata.expensetype" class="input--style-1" placeholder="Enter expense type" requied />*@
                    <select ng-model="expensesdata.expensetype" name="expensetype" required="">
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
                        <option value="Bill">Bill</option>
                        <option value="Purchases">Purchases</option>
                        <option value="return">return</option>
                        <option value="fuels">fuels</option>
                    </select>
                    <span ng-show="addexpense.expensetype.$error.required">Expense type is required</span>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="number" name="amount" ng-model="expensesdata.amount" min="0" ng-minlength="0" class="input--style-1" placeholder="Enter amount" required="">
                    <span ng-show="addexpense.amount.$error.required">Amount is required</span>
                    <span ng-show="addexpense.amount.$error.minlength">Enter valid amount</span>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" name="detail" ng-model="expensesdata.detail" class="input--style-1" placeholder="Enter details" required="">
                    <span ng-show="addexpense.detail.$error.required">Detail is required</span>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input ng-model="expensesdata.date" name="date" class="input--style-1 js-datepicker" placeholder="Select date">
                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-calendar-note input-icon js-btn-calendar"></i>
                    @*<span ng-show="addexpense.date.$error.required">Date is required</span>*@
                </div>

                <br />
                <br />
                <input type="button" ng-disabled="addexpense.expensetype.$invalid ||addexpense.amount.$invalid ||addexpense.detail.$invalid ||addexpense.date.$invalid " value="Add record" ng-click="addnewexpense()" class="btn btn--radius btn--green btn-small" />
                <br />
            </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please show the request body which is send from the client-side when you click 'Add record'?

Comment: this is a service that i use ito sent request .             
   app.service('addrecordservice', function () {
    this.addrecordfunc = function ($scope) {
        
       
      //  alert("add data" + $scope.expensesdata[0].date);
        
        
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/login/Addnewexpenses",
            data: $scope.expensesdata,
            success: function (result) {
                if (result == "Add") {
                   
                    window.location.href = "/login/dashboard";
                }

Comment: else {
                    alert("error in editing");
                }
            }

        });
    }
});